# Node js express res.redirect not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have following code and it's failing to redirect to a html page. Intention is to redirect the request to a login page as soon as GET request is received on '/'

```
var express=require('express')
var cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var ServerApp=express();

ServerApp.get('/',function (req,res){
        res.redirect('./login.html');
        res.end();

});

ServerApp.listen(8080,function(){
                console.log('Server now listening on port 8080...')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add express.static middleware to serve static files. ServerApp.use(express.static(__dirname)); does the job.